# Вывод определенного текста в угол экрана в python

Tags: python

Как можно сделать вывод текста в угол экрана, чтобы выглядело примерно так: [image: В углу текст.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала неплохо было бы указать, с помощью чего вы хотите реализовать свою задачу. А уж если вы еще и свой код покажете, то будет просто замечательно.

Предположим, будем делать все при помощи модуля PIL
Тогда получается такой код:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

img = Image.open("gramota.png")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
width, height = img.size

unicode_font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", 16)
posx= width-100 #координаты теста
posy=5
draw.text ((posx,posy), u'Тут текст', font=unicode_font, fill='red' )
img.save('outimage.png')
```

получим:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Координаты текста либо подбирайте сами методом проб и ошибок, либо воспользуйтесь алгоритмом по типу, приведенному [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902198/pil-how-to-scale-text-size-in-relation-to-the-size-of-the-image)

Comment: Имхо, автор вполне однозначно написал, что ему нужно. Он хочет выводить надпись не в в какой-то файл с изображением, а прямо на экран.